# Django-CMS 3.0.3 Publishing a page duplicates data from plugin django-cms-saq

Tags: django, python-2.7, plugins, django-cms

Django-cms-saq is tested for 2.4.x.  I'm trying to update the program to work with 3.0.X.

So far, I've updated all the imports but am coming across an unusual error.  When I add a question (a plugin) to a page and hit publish, it creates two copies of the question in the database (viewable through the admin site).  Deleting either copy removes both from the published page but leaves the question in edit mode.

How would I go about trouble shooting this?

I will include some of the files here.  Please let me know if you need any other files.

Note that I am trying to add a multiple-choice question.

From models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Max, Sum

from cms.models import CMSPlugin, Page, Placeholder
from cms.models.fields import PageField
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

from djangocms_text_ckeditor.models import AbstractText

...

class Question(CMSPlugin):
    QUESTION_TYPES = [
        ('S', 'Single-choice question'),
        ('M', 'Multi-choice question'),
        ('F', 'Free-text question'),
    ]

    slug = models.SlugField(
        help_text="A slug for identifying answers to this specific question "
        "(allows multiple only for multiple languages)")
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
    help_text = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION_TYPES)
    optional = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text="Only applies to free text questions",
    )

    depends_on_answer = models.ForeignKey(
        Answer, null=True, blank=True, related_name='trigger_questions')

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        for answer in oldinstance.answers.all():
            answer.pk = None
            answer.question = self
            answer.save()

        self.depends_on_answer = oldinstance.depends_on_answer

    @staticmethod
    def all_in_tree(page):
        root = page.get_root()
        # Remember that there might be questions on the root page as well!
        tree = root.get_descendants() | Page.objects.filter(id=root.id)
        placeholders = Placeholder.objects.filter(page__in=tree)
        return Question.objects.filter(placeholder__in=placeholders)

    @staticmethod
    def all_in_page(page):
        placeholders = Placeholder.objects.filter(page=page)
        return Question.objects.filter(placeholder__in=placeholders)

    def score(self, answers):
        if self.question_type == 'F':
            return 0
        elif self.question_type == 'S':
            return self.answers.get(slug=answers).score
        elif self.question_type == 'M':
            answers_list = answers.split(',')
            return sum([self.answers.get(slug=a).score for a in answers_list])

    @property
    def max_score(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_max_score'):
            if self.question_type == "S":
                self._max_score = self.answers.aggregate(
                    Max('score'))['score__max']
            elif self.question_type == "M":
                self._max_score = self.answers.aggregate(
                    Sum('score'))['score__sum']
            else:
                self._max_score = None  # don't score free-text answers
        return self._max_score

    def percent_score_for_user(self, user):
        if self.max_score:
            try:
                score = Submission.objects.get(
                    question=self.slug,
                    user=user,
                ).score
            except Submission.DoesNotExist:
                return 0
            return 100.0 * score / self.max_score
        else:
            return None

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug

...
```

From cms_plugins.py

```
import itertools
import operator

from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool

from cms_saq.models import Question, Answer, GroupedAnswer, Submission, \
        FormNav, ProgressBar, SectionedScoring, ScoreSection, BulkAnswer, \
        QuestionnaireText, SubmissionSetReview


from djangocms_text_ckeditor.cms_plugins import TextPlugin
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.models import Text

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...

class QuestionPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = Question
    module = "SAQ"
    inlines = [AnswerAdmin]
    exclude = ('question_type',)

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        user = context['request'].user

        submission_set = None

        triggered = True
        depends_on = None
        if instance.depends_on_answer:
            depends_on = instance.depends_on_answer.pk
            try:
                Submission.objects.get(
                    user=user,
                    question=instance.depends_on_answer.question.slug,
                    answer=instance.depends_on_answer.slug,
                    submission_set=submission_set,
                )
                triggered = True
            except:
                triggered = False

        extra = {
            'question': instance,
            'answers': instance.answers.all(),
            'triggered': triggered,
            'depends_on': depends_on,
        }

        if user.is_authenticated():
            try:
                extra['submission'] = Submission.objects.get(
                    user=user,
                    question=instance.slug,
                    submission_set=submission_set,
                )
            except Submission.DoesNotExist:
                pass

        context.update(extra)
        return context

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.question_type = self.question_type
        super(QuestionPlugin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)


...


class MultiChoiceQuestionPlugin(QuestionPlugin):
    name = "Multi Choice Question"
    render_template = "cms_saq/multi_choice_question.html"
    question_type = "M"
    exclude = ('question_type', 'help_text')

...

plugin_pool.register_plugin(SingleChoiceQuestionPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(MultiChoiceQuestionPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(DropDownQuestionPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(GroupedDropDownQuestionPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(FreeTextQuestionPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(FreeNumberQuestionPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(FormNavPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(SubmissionSetReviewPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(SectionedScoringPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(ProgressBarPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(BulkAnswerPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(SessionDefinition)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(QuestionnaireTextPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(TranslatedTextPlugin)
```

From cms_app.py:

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class CMSSaq(CMSApp):
    name = _("Self Assessment")
    urls = ["cms_saq.urls"]

apphook_pool.register(CMSSaq)
```

Additional information:

This duplicative observation creates an issue when trying get the question object via its slug `Question.objects.get(slug=question_slug)`.  Such a query should only return one question.  What we get here is two questions returned.

```
import re

from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST, require_GET
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.utils import simplejson, datastructures
from django.conf import settings

from cms_saq.models import Question, Answer, Submission, SubmissionSet

ANSWER_RE = re.compile(r'^[\w-]+(,[\w-]+)*$')


@require_POST
def _submit(request):

    post_data = datastructures.MultiValueDict(request.POST)
    submission_set_tag = post_data.pop('submission_set_tag', '')

    for question_slug, answers in post_data.iteritems():

        # validate the question
        try:
            question = Question.objects.get(
                slug=question_slug,
                #placeholder__page__publisher_is_draft=False,
            )
        except Question.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest(
                "Invalid question '%s'" % question_slug,
            )

        # check answers is a list of slugs
        if question.question_type != 'F' and not ANSWER_RE.match(answers):
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Invalid answers: %s" % answers)
        # validate and score the answer
        try:
            score = question.score(answers)
        except Answer.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest(
                "Invalid answer '%s:%s'" % (question_slug, answers)
            )

        # save, but don't update submissions belonging to an existing set
        filter_attrs = {
            'user': request.user.id,
            'question': question_slug,
            'submission_set': None,
        }

        attrs = {'answer': answers, 'score': score}

        rows = Submission.objects.filter(**filter_attrs).update(**attrs)

        if not rows:
            attrs.update(filter_attrs)
            Submission.objects.create(**attrs)

    # Create submission set if requested
    if submission_set_tag:
        submission_set_tag = submission_set_tag[0]

        if submission_set_tag:
            _create_submission_set(
                request, submission_set_tag
            )

    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a page in CMS, and add plugins to it, once you hit publish the CMS creates a copy of each of those plugins as they are at that point in time. This gives the page a live version, and enables you to then make changes to it which are held in draft mode, until you hit publish again.

This allows you to have a draft version of the site where edits/changes can be made and finalised before making them public.

Seeing two copies for each plugin therefore, isn't a problem.

As a side note, I'd strongly recommend you join the CMS user group on Google Plus if you're developing CMS sites; https://plus.google.com/communities/107689498573071376044

**update**

Ok, so a plugin in CMS is attached to a placeholder which is on a page, and it's the page that has two version of itself. Because each plugin attaches to a page, you can use that relationship to filter your plugins.

If you register your plugin with admin, or to object calls on it you're just looking at what is stored in your table, which as I say, includes the draft and live version of plugins.

So when you're querying for your plugin do this;

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(placeholder__page__publisher_is_draft=True)
```

This will get you all the questions which are attached to draft pages.

The only drawback to this is that plugins are guaranteed to be attached to a `Page()` object unless the plugin is set to `page_only = True` but I've only ever been interested in plugins attached to pages so it works for me. See the [docs](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#page-only) for more info on this.

Furthermore, if you're ever adding CMS page links to any of your plugins, please don't forget to add a similar argument to your model field to ensure that you limit the page objects to draft only;

```
page_link = models.ForeignKey(
    Page,
    limit_choices_to={'publisher_is_draft': True},
    help_text=_("Link to another page on the site."),
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='myapp_page_link'
)
```

Comment: I've seen this explanation before.  It may be a red-herring because, as far as I can tell, this duplicative paradigm was the same in CMS 2.4.x, where CMS-SAQ worked.

Comment: @Brian ok, so what exactly is not working? I'll edit my answer with some troubleshooting for the correct duplication of a plugin.

Comment: Thanks @marksweb!  I've edited my question to provide a bit more information.  Please excuse me if I'm not too clear or miss-use terminology.  I'm learning.

Comment: No problem, this sounds like something I had back when I started with CMS. I'll see if I can dig out some code to help.

Comment: @Brian I've updated my answer. Hopefully that explains things!

Comment: So, I think that you've solved it.  The following code was in the code right where you said it should be: `#placeholder__page__publisher_is_draft=False,`

Comment: That will filter for all the live versions, you want all the draft versions because it's draft mode you edit. Publishing then creates the live versions. So swap that False for True if you're looking to render to a page which then will get published.

Comment: Bit of a necro-post, but – Ran into this same issue with 3.4.x. Encountered an additional problem because the plugin I was displaying in the admin was also part of a Static Placeholder (which means it will never have a "page"). Had to dip into django Q's to do it, but managed it some how. Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/aubricus/23217efdfe8a1a6539b2b873e4c1e665